# UITableView - align cell image to top left

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView where I set the height to be larger than default (using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. The image in the cell is always 32x32 and us currently being vertically aligned to center. I'd like that the image will be at the top of the cell. I tried something like this (setting the bounds explicitly):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(7,7,32,32);
    ....
    }
    ....
}
```

but this doesn't work. Any simple way to make it without creating a complete custom cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this article here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

You can do some pretty custom modifications if you play with the content view, you just need to know how to do it ;)

Comment: it doesn't say how to change the built in image view, but I ended up adding my own image view and this works well